# Can Any one help me to convert this sql query into linq

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq

I need to convert this SQL Query to Link :

```
"Select * FROM [Register] 
 where RegisterId IN (SELECT MyId 
                      FROM Friends 
                      WHERE FriendId='" + Session["CurrentProfileId"] + "' 
                      AND Status=1 

                      UNION 

                      SELECT FriendId 
                      FROM Friends 
                      WHERE MyId='" + Session["CurrentProfileId"] + "' 
                      AND Status=1) ";
```

---

It may be look like this??? but this is incorrect and having errors

```
(from u in db.Register
 where RegisterId).Contains
        (from f in db.Freinds
         where f.MyId == Id && m.Status == 1
         select new { m.MyId })
        .Union(from m in db.Freinds
               where f.FreindId == Id && m.Status == 1
               select new { m.CreateDate } ));
```

Comment: What are you needing to learn? Linq? C#? MSSQL?

Comment: I am learning LINQ and i need to convert Sql Query to Linq, I am struggling in LINQ .

Comment: Actually I am doing all that stuff in Asp.net mvc , facing problems in LINQ

Comment: COnsider deleting your question, as it is not so relevant.

Comment: My Question is simple, How to convert upper sql query into linq..Thats All!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few problems with the linq above and here are a few:

1. In the query in the `Union` you select the `CreateDate` whereas in the top on you select the `MyId`. I assume you meant to select `FreindId`.
2. In these 2 queries you create an anonymous class instance with the field but then compare it to the `RegisterId` which is probably a `guid`/`string`/`int` - but for sure not of the type you just created.
3. You are using the `Contains` method wrong. Linq syntax can be similar to sql but it is not the same. Check here for [`Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339118(v=vs.110).aspx)

The correct Linq way of doing it is:

```
var idsCollection = ((from f in db.Freinds
                     where f.StatusId == 1 && f.MyId == Id
                     select f.MyId)
                   .Union(from m in db.Friends
                          where m.StatusId == 1 && f.FreindId == Id
                          select m.FriendId)).ToList();

var result = (from u in db.Register
             where idsCollection.Contains(u.RegisterId)
             select u).ToList();
```

*Notice that the `.ToList()` is not a must and is here just to ease in debugging. For more information about this `.ToList()` and Linq in general check MSDN*

Comment: Gilad Green ,You are Awesome It works Perfectly, Respect You Sir, Thank You So Much

Comment: @UmerKhan - apparently you accidentally unmarked it after you marked it

Comment: but unable to to solve last line and R.RegisterId !=Session[UserId]

Comment: I am sorry - Gilad Green- I Actually dont want to hurt you! You helped me I am fan of you. Please ignore it